# How to print to a Bluetooth printer from a .Net Maui Android app

Tags: android, .net, bluetooth, maui

I want to connect a Maui Android app to a bluetooth printer and print simple text to it. The printers should be treated as generic - there should not be a need to have dedicated SDKs for each printer model.

Using the following code I can connect to the Bluetooth printer.

```cs
const string ArduinoBluetoothTransceiverName = "MPT-II";
var connector = DependencyService.Get<IBluetoothConnector>();
connector.Connect(ArduinoBluetoothTransceiverName);
```

Printing is the main challenge.

Comment: What have you tried?  What specific problem are you having?  There are numerous questions on doing this with Xamarin that should also ply to MAUI

Comment: Do you have a device that you can test on?

Comment: Yes i have a device- no brand 58mm bluetooth printer that is just written Mobile Printer. I downloaded an android app to test and i can print to it.

Comment: @Jason had gone through an article that said that wouldnt work. Maybe you can share how to do it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+bluetooth+printer+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jason. using .Net Maui Andriod app with net7 I can connect to a generic Bluetooth printer and print simple text.

```
 public async Task Print(string deviceName, byte[] imageData)
        {
            using (BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter)
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                BluetoothDevice device = (from bd in bluetoothAdapter?.BondedDevices
                                          where bd?.Name == deviceName
                                          select bd).FirstOrDefault();
                try
                {
                    using (BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = device?.
                        CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")))
                    {
                        bluetoothSocket?.Connect();
                        stream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
                       // stream.Write(SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE, 0, SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE.Length);
                        var bytes = stream.ToArray();
                        bluetoothSocket?.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        bluetoothSocket.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    throw exp;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Simba, could you please name the assembly used in this example?